# Constants representation/design

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums

I need a way of structuring a tree of constants in java.

For an API I have:action/request name and for each action a specific number of parameters

```
API_V00
    action_1: param_1,param_2 ...;
    action_2: param_3,param_4 ...;
    ......
```

I want to have `action_1`, `action_2`, `param_1`, `param_2`, etc., represented as constants/enum and access them as:

```
API_V00.action_1 -> this should return a string with value "action_1"
API_V00.action_2 -> this should return a string with value "action_2"


API_V00.action_1.param_1 -> this should return a string with value "param_1"
API_V00.action_1.param_2 -> this should return a string with value "param_2"
API_V00.action_2.param_3 -> this should return a string with value "param_3"
API_V00.action_2.param_4 ......
```

I tried creating an enum with the actions and I have the `API_V00.action_1` -> return a string  but now I don't have a way of binding the prams name to each action to have this kind of access type to the params `action_1.param_1`, etc.

Comment: Usually something like this would be implemented using accessor methods. Is there any reason why you need it to be done with field access? Do the actions all have the same number of `param_*` parameters?

Comment: the number of prams are different to each command/action

Comment: I wont to have a way of selecting the exact parameter without getting that one from a list. And hoped that will be a way of representing a constant inside an enum value

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should create a simple class to wrap the action+param pairs. If you want this to be more constant-like, you can make the constructor private and provide some "pre-instantiated" instances. For instance, something like this might work:

```
public class ParameterizedAction {
    public static ParameterizedAction API_V00
        = new ParameterizedAction(action_1, "param_1", "param_2", ...);
    // etc for the others

    private final Action action;
    private final String[] params;

    private ParameterizedAction(Action action, String... parameters) {
        this.action = action;
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public Action getAction() {
        return action;
    }

    public String parameter(int idx) {
        return parameters[idx];
    }
}
```

Comment: and how I will access a parameter for one action ? to be as  ParameterizedAction.API_V00.

Comment: I just updated it. But basically, you access a parameter like you'd access anything else -- with a getter function.